# Reference request for a paper of Berard-Bergery

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, paper-request

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a pdf copy of the following paper by Lionel Berard-Bergery:

*"Scalar curvature and isometry group", in Spectra of Riemannian Manifolds, Kaigai Publications, Tokyo, 1983.*

It seems to be a well-known work judging by some of the citations, but not available on MathSciNet.

Comment: No paper is available on MathSciNet. MathSciNet provides, or does not provide, a link.

Comment: these are the libraries that have it: https://www.worldcat.org/title/spectra-of-riemannian-manifolds-proceedings-of-the-france-japan-seminar-on-spectra-of-riemannian-manifolds-and-space-of-metrics-of-manifolds-kyoto-1981/oclc/493443453

Comment: I don't know if you're still interested, but I have a copy that  I can email to you.  You can easily figure out my email address by starting with my MO profile.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks! But I managed to find one in the meantime :)